# Atom and ide not working

Tags: terminal, python3, atom-editor

platformio-ide-terminal package is not working with the new update of the atom. How can I use a terminal within the atom? the package is not installing causing an error.

Comment: 1) You rollback your Atom version to the previous one; 2) Wait for the package to be update/use an alternative

Comment: How to roll back?